# Are Claris(ST-2400) shifters drop-in replacements for St-2300s?

Tags: shimano, shifter, upgrades

I've got 2300s on my bike. I don't much like the little thumb levers. I'd like to upgrade to Claris shifters, but I need to minimise the costs.

Can I just change the shifters? They're both 8 speed (and double, in my case), but are the cables compatible as well?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've now upgraded, and they are indeed drop in replacements, only much improved. The ergonomics are much better, and the changes themselves seem much more positive. If only mapmyride wasn't currently buggy and losing all time data, I could demonstrate improved performance too! (probably just the placebo effect, though)

Comment: Are they equivalent in terms of brake travel ? I would like to fit Shimano 105 brakes (BR-5800) to my bike fitted with with ST-2300 shifters, but the compatibility sheet only lists ST-2400 as a suitable fit ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. They're compatible between 2300 and 2400, it seesm but I've no idea about 105

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I test rode a Sora a few years ago with those thumb shifters - truly awful.

My gut feel (I know Shimano well, but don't have direct experience of this groupset) is that one is a direct replacement for the other, but the only evidence I can find to back this is [a review on Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/product-reviews/B00HYH4JKO).

For sure there'll be no problems shifting, because you're staying at 8-speed. I was just a bit hesitant to answer in case something to do with the braking might have changed. But that guy's review suggests you'll be ok - sounds like he did exactly what you're proposing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Both shift 8 speed shimano clusters. The spacing on 8 speed clusters has stayed the same since they first came out. So any 8 speed shimano compatible shifter is a replacement for any other.

Comment: Thanks. Including the cable set? I.e. can I re-use the cables I already have? The review says they come with cables, but I'll probably be getting used ones which almost certainly will not come with them

Comment: @Paul Cables will be fine, they are consistent across the range